# Add Native DLL to Existing COM+ Application using WIX

Tags: wix, wix3.5, com+

I need to add a native DLL to an existing COM+ application while installing some components using WIX. Is this possible? if so how?

I have a component something like this:

```
<Component Id="C.My.dll" Guid="AGIUD" DiskId="1" Location="local">
    <File Id="My.dll" Name="my.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="{MyDllsLocation}" />
    <complus:ComPlusApplication Id="COMPlusAppName" Name="COMPlusAppName">
        <complus:ComPlusAssembly Id="My.dll" Type="native" DllPath="[#C.My.dll]">
            <complus:ComPlusComponent  Id="MyComponent" CLSID="ACLSID" />
        </complus:ComPlusAssembly>
    </complus:ComPlusApplication>
</Component>
```

But because my COM+ application already exists I get an error when I run the installer.

I am hoping to be able to add the DLL into the existing COM+ application, since this is an add-on to our core product, and the Application will already exist.

I have had a look at the tutorial about COM+ applications ([here](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/com-applications)) and the documentation for the ComPlusAppliucation element ([here](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/complus_xsd_complusapplication.htm)) but there doesn't seem to be an obvious answer...

Thanks in advance for your help!

(I am using WIX 3.5)